# How to chomp previous line regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following input:

```
-- input  --
Keep this
Chomp this
ChompHere:
Anything below gets chomped
```

And I need the output to look like:

```
-- output (expected) --
Keep this
```

Right now I get the following based on the code below:

```
-- output (actual) --
Keep this
Chomp this
```

**ASK**: How can I delete the previous line of a regex match (Chomp this):

```
public void chompPreviousLine() {
    String text = "Keep this\n"
            + "Chomp this\nChompHere:\nAnything below gets chomped";
    Pattern CHOMP= Pattern.compile("^(ChompHere:(.*))$", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = CHOMP.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
        // chomp everything below and one line above!
        text = m.replaceAll("");
        // but....??? how to delete the previous line ???
        text = text .replaceAll("[\n]+$", "");  // delete any remaining /n
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a case where some text to keep is on a separate line between `Chomp this` and `ChompHere:`?

Comment: I am not sure what is your problem. Your code is looking for anything that starts with `ChompHere:` and remove it. If you replace this part of your regex with `Chomp this` you will get expected output. Anyway, wouldn't it be easier to use `text.substring(0,text.indexOf("Chomp this\n")).trim()`?

Comment: Does it have to use regex? Can be done pretty easily with a simple loop processing input line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the regex so that it also gets the previous line:

```
Pattern CHOMP= Pattern.compile("[^\n]+\nChompHere:(.*)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

`[^\n]+\n` will match any consecutive character that is not an end-of-line character then the end-of-line itself. Since it is before `ChompHere` in the regex, it will match the complete line before `ChompHere`.

I have removed parenthesis since you don't really use groups in your algorithm; you are indeed replacing the whole matching text.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positive look-ahead:

```
^(.*)(?=ChompHere:)
```

Depending on whether you want the line break matched or not, you have to add it to the lookahead.

But would a simple parser not be easier for this?

Comment: @JaJ, I don't see how this would solve your problem at all. In a way it's the opposite of what you seem to be asking for.

Comment: I spoke too soon...I thought I had this working but adding a \n match in the regex worked.

Comment: My bad, had it the wrong way arround. Positive lookahead is the most canonical solution, though.